# Show hidden .htaccess files by default

Tags: hidden-files

I was wondering if there is some method to display `.htaccess` files by default in every folder i create it.

Is it possible to **exclude .htaccess files from the hidden files**?
Maybe from the terminal

Answer (score 14):

You can use `Ctrl+H` if you are browsing files using Ubuntu File Browser (Nautilus)

Comment: Can we set somehow Nemo or Nautilus, to show hidden files per directory like  sorting, for example?

Answer (score 8):

You can set an alias to `ls` so that it will always list 'dot' files; the syntax varies a bit depending of the shell used; for bash it is:

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

Add the above line to your ~/.bashrc. The drawback is this will list all files starting with a dot, every time.

Comment: I'd also recommend `alias ls='ls -a --color=auto'`

Answer (score 0):

In linux, every file with a "dot" in the start of its name is treated as hidden file. Being hidden is not some property that you can remove from a file, thereby excluding that file from hidden files. If you want to unhide a file, you need to change its name i.e if you want to remove **.somefile** from hidden files, you rename it to **somefile**. But I dont think that you can do the same with **.htaccess** because its a configuration file and if you rename it to **htaccess** your webserver will still be looking for **.htaccess**.

So, in short, I don't think it is possible to exclude .htaccess files from hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted only to show the the `.htaccess` dot file but keep the rest hidden you could add an alias to your bash configuration file for `ls` that uses `grep` to filter out the non-htaccess dotfiles.

```
alias ls='ls -a | grep ".*([.]htaccess$)|.*\d{2}:\d{2} ([^.].*$)|.*$"'
```

That regular expression is not working by the way, maybe someone with more experience could write the correct solution. But this method should give you what you want.